Is there a counter example to disprove the following regarding vector addition in binary field?
Let $\{\mathbf{a}_1 , \mathbf{a}_2 , \mathbf{a}_3 , ...., \mathbf{a}_{30}\}\subset \mathbb{F}_2^{15}$ denote the set of binary vectors. Define the set of integers $\{p_k\}_{k=1}^{14}$ as$3 \leq p_1 < p_2 < p_3 <....< p_{14} \leq 30$. Now, define the two sets as
$$\mathcal{H}:=\{(\mathbf{a}_1+ \mathbf{a}_{p_k})\mod2 : \forall 1 \leq k \leq 14\},$$
$$ \mathcal{G}:=\{(\mathbf{a}_2+ \mathbf{a}_{p_k})\mod2 : \forall 1 \leq k \leq 14\}.$$
Now, given that $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{G} \subset \{\mathbf{a}_1 , \mathbf{a}_2 , \mathbf{a}_3 , ...., \mathbf{a}_{30}\}$, and $\big|\mathcal{H}\big| = \big|\mathcal{G}\big|= 14$, then is it necessarily the case that $\mathbf{a}_1 = \mathbf{a}_2$? I am trying to find a counter example to disprove my assertion.
Any help regarding this will be very much appreciated.

Perhaps some background regarding where this problem arose would help readers understand why your assertion is of any interest.

Are you requiring $\mathcal H=\mathcal G$ to hold for every sequence of integers $p_1<p_2<\cdots$? Or does it suffice to find one sequence where this happens

For example, if we fix a vector $b$, select $a_1=0$, $a_2=b$, $a_{2i+1}$ arbitrary, $a_{2i+2}=a_{2i+1}+b$, $p_1=3$, $p_2=4$, $p_3=5$, $\ldots$, $p_{14}=16$. Then we always have $a_{2i+1}+a_1=a_{2i+2}+a_2$ as well as $a_{2i+1}+a_2=a_{2i+3}+a_1$. The way I read it, this is a counter example, but it is not clear I have interpreted the requirements the way you intended them.
